# Dynamic String Manipulation in Knime

Tags: r, knime

I want to dyanamically change my URL at runtime for which I did string manipulations in R and it worked with this script:

```
x <- 'https://news.google.com/search?q='
var <- 'NREGA'
z <- '&hl=en-IN&gl=IN&ceid=IN%3Aen'
url <- paste0(x, var,z, collapse = '')

url
```

Now I want to change this variable `var` dynamically and the value for `var` needs to be retrieved from a knime node which can then be used in url. In my case it's the table creator node in knime to get this value but I'm not able to assign it to `var`.

[image]

Kindly suggest any knime node by which the value for 'var' can be obtained and then be used in 'R snippet' node in knime, and can be used in manipulating the url.

Answer (score 0):

The first line of the code in your image is

`knime.in <- knime.flow.in[["NREGA"]]`

The expression `knime.flow.in[["NREGA"]]` in an R script node gets you the value of the flow variable named `NREGA`.

You probably don't want to assign that value to `knime.in` as that's the R dataframe containing the table from the input port of the KNIME node. Either you want to use that table - in which case don't overwrite it - or you don't, in which case just use the `R Source (Table)` node which has no input port.

Later on in your code you have the line

`var <- knime.flow.in[["NREGA"]]`

which should assign the flow variable value to the R variable `var`. If that isn't working the way you want, please edit your question to better describe what the problem is.